relation between heat kernels of Laplace type operators that differ by endomorphisms
My question is the following: Let $E\to M$ be a vector bundle over a closed manifold and $\Delta$ be a Laplace type operator acting, a priori, on smooth sections of $E.$ Let $A\in \Gamma(\mathrm{End}(E))$ be a smooth self-adjoint section of the endomorphism bundle of E. My main question what is the relation between the heat kernels of $\Delta$ and $\Delta+A$?. In other words,  Do we have a relation between
$e^{-t(\Delta+A)}$ and $e^{-tA}e^{-t\Delta}$?
I am particularly interested in the near-diagonal, $t\to0+$, expansions of both heat kernels and I would like to know if the expansion of the simpler one is enough to get the expansion of the other one. This is probably well-known but I do not really know where to look for an answer. Some references would be highly appreciated.
Thanks
